# расшифровать строку шифр

Tags: алгоритм

U2FsdGVkX1+3/0wYFxaOTH6R0Yy1ZifUujR2WtHT8nI=
ключ не нашел
алгоритм не знаю

Comment: `Salted__\xB7\xFFL\x8EL~\x91ь\xB5f'Ժ4vZ\xD1\xD3\xF2r` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX1+3/0wYFxaOTH6R0Yy1ZifUujR2WtHT8nI=" | base64 -d | hexdump -C


00000000  53 61 6c 74 65 64 5f 5f  b7 ff 4c 18 17 16 8e 4c  |Salted__..L....L|
00000010  7e 91 d1 8c b5 66 27 d4  ba 34 76 5a d1 d3 f2 72  |~....f'..4vZ...r|
00000020
```

Pасшифровал `Salted__LL~ьf'Ժ4vZr` . Дальше нужен пароль.

Это похоже на OpenSSL salted format

Информации о типе шифрования в файле нет.

http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/OpenSSL_salted_format

Comment: как он должен выглядеть  этот пароль?

Comment: любая строка с любым количеством символов

Comment: но так как тело короткое возможно в файле ничего интересного нет

Comment: Что-то кучи символов не хватает по сравнению с моим результатом.

Comment: непечатаемые ненапечатались)  32 байта всего, 8 заголовок плюс соль минимуи 8, 16 байт на тело остается

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что это base64. А вот что с ним дальше делать - тебе виднее.

```js
var s = atob("U2FsdGVkX1+3/0wYFxaOTH6R0Yy1ZifUujR2WtHT8nI=")
console.log(s)
console.log([...s].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).join(" "))
```